# Changing Char x to Char y in a Array.

Tags: c++, arrays

In the following code I am running into an issue with mutating an array. My question is **why doesn't the funOne function mutate the array that I pass in?**

```
#include <iostream>

void funOne(char *arr, char x, char y, int z);
void print(char *array);

void print(char *array){
std::cout << array << std::endl;
}

void funOne(char *arr, char x, char y, int z){
    z =  sizeof(arr);
    for(int i = 0; i<z; i++){
    if(arr[i] == x){
    x == y; 
    }

    }

}

int main(){

    char arra[] = {'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'};

    funOne(arra, 'a', 'c', 10);

    print(arra);



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nothing about this program even comes close to modifying `arr`...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit besides me passing in arra into the function? Makes sense.

Comment: Just passing an array into a function doesn't magically mutate it.

Comment: `z =  sizeof(arr);` Will change z to the size of the pointer. Why even do this when you pass in the arrays length?

Comment: Hint: Learn the basics of the language.

Comment: aand Your print function doesn't print the array it prints the pointer. You need to put a loop in your print function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x == y;
```

Whoops...?

- The `==` operator is for comparing things;
- The `=` operator is for assigning things.

Furthermore, I guess you wanted to assign to `arr[i]`, not `x`:

```
arr[i] = y;
```

Take greater care.

Your final problem is that `z` will be wrong, because `arr` is not your array but a pointer to your array… and `sizeof(char*)` is fixed. You will have to pass the array's length in to the function as another argument.

Or, y'know, use a `std::vector` seeing as this is the 21st century!!